# can spring batch be used as job framework for non batch jobs (regular job)

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible to use spring batch as a regular job framework?

I want to create a device service (microservice) that has the responsibility
to get events and trigger jobs on devices. The devices are remote so it will take time for the job to be complete, but it is not a batch job (not periodically running or partitioning large data set).

I am wondering whether spring batch can still be used a job framework, or if it is only for batch processing. If the answer is no, what jobs framework (besides writing your own) are famous?

**Job Description:**

1. I need to execute against a specific device a job that will contain several steps. Each step will communicate with a device and wait for a device to confirm it executed the former command given to it.
2. I need retry, recovery and scheduling features (thought of combining spring batch with quartz)
3. Regarding read-process-write, I am basically getting a command request regarding a device, I do a little DB reads and then start long waiting periods that all need to pass in order for the job/task to be successful.

Also, I can choose (justify) relevant IMDG/DB. Concurrency is outside the scope (will be outside the job mechanism). An alternative that came to mind was akka actors. (job for a device will create children actors as steps)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - **not periodically running or partitioning large data set** are not primary requirements for usage of Spring Batch.

Spring Batch is basically a **read - process - write** framework where reading & processing happens item by item and writing happens in chunks ( for chunk oriented processing ) .

So you can use Spring Batch if your job logic fits into - **read - process - write** paradigm and rest of the things seem secondary to me.

Also, with Spring Batch , you should also evaluate the part about **Job Repository** . Spring Batch needs a database ( either in memory or on disk ) to store job meta data and its not optional.

I think, you should put more explanation as why you need a **Job Framework** and what kind of logic you are running that you are calling it a **Job** so I will revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, here we go :) 

1. I need to execute against a specific device a job that will contain several steps. Each step will communicate with a device and wait for
a device to confirm it executed the former command given to it.

2. I need retry, recovery and scheduling features (thought of combining spring batch with quartz)

3. Regarding read-process-write, I am basically getting a command request regarding a device, I do a little DB reads and then start long waiting periods that all need to pass in order for the job/task to be successful.

Comment: Also, I can choose (justify) relevant IMDG/DB.
Concurrency is outside the scope (will be outside the job mechanism).
An alternative that came to mind was akka actors. (job for a device will create children actors as steps).

Comment: np, I have ported your comments to your question description.